# Dynamic SQL - How can you use it to run a SELECT against all schema's and Tables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

**Scenario**

I have a database that contains all of our customer data, which is separated by 
Schemas. For example:

```
Customer1 = Schema1, 
Customer2 = Schema2, 
Customer3 = Schema3, 
etc...
```

Sometimes we get an issue where a Date value in a table is sometimes NULL. This table is contained in every Schema, but can sometimes be called 'Tasks', 'Tasks_NEW' or 'Task_NEW' (got to love consistency).

I am looking for a way that I can dynamically run a SELECT statement that will return a count of all NULL Date values, across all Tables and all Schemas.

So far, I have done this in order to put the Schema, plus the Table into a TempTable;

```
CREATE TABLE #TASK_TABLES
(   ID      INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    TenantID        INT,
    TableName       NVARCHAR(255)   )

INSERT INTO #TASK_TABLES
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
FROM [Dynamic].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
AND TABLE_NAME IN ('Tasks', 'Task_NEW', 'Tasks_NEW')
ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA
```

Now that I have this information, I want to cycle through it with a SELECT like this;

```
SELECT Schema, COUNT(Date)
FROM [Dynamic].[Schema].[Table] (NOLOCK)
WHERE DATE IS NULL
```

Sadly, I don't fully know how to write Dynamic SQL as I'm still learning, but I was hoping that someone might be able to point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is self explanatory code. Alternatively you can use [sp_ineachdb (written by Aaron Bertrand)](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5686/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server-using-spineachdb/).

```
 set nocount on
  -- create temp table .. 
 create table #commandsToRun (currentDB sysname, schemaName sysname, TableName sysname, columnName sysname, datatype sysname, commandToRun nvarchar(max))
 insert into #commandsToRun
SELECT   
        db_name() as CurrentDB, SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.schema_id) as SchemaName, tbl.name AS TableName,
         c.name AS ColumnName, tp.name as DataType, 
         N'select count('+c.name+') as TotalDateColumnAsNULL, '
                    + ''''+SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.schema_id)+'''' + ' as  SchemaName, '
                    + ''''+tbl.name + ''''+ ' AS TableName' + ''
                    +' from '+ db_name() +'.' + SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.schema_id) 
                    +'.'+ tbl.name +' with (nolock) where '
                    +c.name+' is NULL'as CommandToRun
FROM
  sys.columns c
JOIN sys.tables tbl ON
  c.object_id = tbl.object_id
JOIN sys.types tp on c.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id
WHERE
  ( c.name = 'Date' -- filter the column that you want to check 
  or tp.name = 'datetime' -- filter the datatype if you dont know the column names 
  )
-- check the contents of the table 
select * from #commandsToRun

-- generate exec() to run the sql generated in the CommandToRun

declare @sqltext nvarchar(max) = N''

select  @sqltext += N'exec ('''+replace(CommandToRun,'''','''''')+'''); '
from #commandsToRun

-- uncomment below to run the sql generated.
-- exec(@sqltext)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the above, Kin. With some modifications I was able to get the script to return everything that I wanted / needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly different approach for this type of dynamic select.

First, create all of the SELECT statements you are looking to do, and put them into a temp table / temp table variable

```
CREATE TABLE #SQL_COMMANDS (
    ID      INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    SQLCmd  NVARCHAR(500)   
)

INSERT INTO #SQL_COMMANDS (SQLcmd)
SELECT 'SELECT schema, Count(*)
FROM [Dynamic].[' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + '] WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE DATE IS NULL'
FROM [Dynamic].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
AND TABLE_NAME IN ('Tasks', 'Task_NEW', 'Tasks_NEW')
ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA
```

Then, concatenate all of the commands into one string, placing UNION or UNION ALL between each command, like this:

```
DECLARE @FullSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @FullSQL = IsNull(@FullSQL + '
UNION ALL
', '' ) + SQLCmd 
FROM #SQL_COMMANDS
```

Finally, run the command:

```
EXEC (@FullSQL)
```

This removes cursors and other looping constructs from your SQL.

Comment: @Tom_W instead of or along with writing you could upvote his answer as well